# Use RecursiveIteratorIterator to parse a file

Tags: android, json, parsing

This a file I get from an url [File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhbvs.png)

With this code...

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(!is_array($val)) {
echo'<pre>';
      echo "$key => $val";
echo'</pre>';
    }
}
```

I get this output

```
date => 20130409
vehicul => bmw
sell => 205
date => 20130409
vehicul=>ford
sell => 508
```

So how can I get value of each item (date , vehicule, sell)

Thanks for help